# How to show in the select menu only the values between "min_participants"and "max_participants" database columns values?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view that shows the details of a specific conference.

Each conference can have multiple registration types. The registration type table has columns like: name, min_participants, max_participants, etc.

In this details conference page Im showing the registration types info of that conference with code below. The registration type name is working fine but then I have a select menu so the user can select how many participants want to register for each registration type. And Im in doubt how to do this part. Because, a user can only select values between the minimum and maximum participants that exist in the database columns min_participants and max_participants.

So for example for the conference with id "1", when the user accesses "app.test/conf/1", it appears a registration type "general" that has "min_participants" column as "1" and "max_participants" as "3" in the database. So in the select menu should only appear the values "1, 2, 3".

Do you know how to do that?I have this select menu static for now because I'm not understanding how to do that.  Maybe with an accessor method "quantityBetweenAttribute" but I'm not understanding how the logic should be in the method.

```
 @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">{{$rtype->name}}</span>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option selected="">1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
    </form>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**Conference model:**

```
class Conference extends Model
{
// A conference has many registration types
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
}   
public function quantityBetweenAttribute() {
    $registrationTypes = $this->registrationTypes();
}
```

**RegistrationType Model:**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think this might work:

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">{{$rtype->name}}</span>
        <form>
            <select>
                @for($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype->max_participants; $i++)
                    <option {{ $i == $selectedType ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $i }}</option>
                @endfor
            </select>
        </form>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Note that you could optionally use the `{{ $i == $selectedType ? 'selected' : '' }}` to set the selected state by passing the variable $selectedType to your view.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but there is one issue. I have 2 registration types. For the first is working fine, it appears the registration type title and then the select menu with only 1,2 and 3 values. But for the other registration type, the title appears correctly but the select menu appears without any selected value and it seems that is disabled. Do you know why can be?

Comment: Are you certain the min and max value of this other-registration-type is set to correct values?

Comment: I would not consider these values to be correct, to be honest. With the construction shown, it is important that the max value is a higher interger than the min value. If you insist the max value can be lower than the min value, I could update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a for loop:

```
@foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <span class="font-weight-semi-bold text-heading-blue">{{$rtype->name}}</span>
        <form>
            <select>
             @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
               <option selected="{{ $i === $rtype->min_participants }}">{{ $i }}</option>
             @endfor
            </select>
    </form>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works, but there is one issue, I have 2 registration types. For the first is working fine, it appears the registration type title and then the select menu with only 1,2 and 3 values. But for the other registration type, the title appears correctly but the select menu appears without any selected value and it seems that is disabled. Do you know why can be?